# GUlp - following tasks did not complete

Tags: gulp

I'm using gulp 4, and i have the following gulpfile.js:

```
'use strict';
var gulp = require('gulp'), del = require('del');

gulp.task('copy-fonts', () => {
    return gulp.src(['node_modules/ng/resources/fonts/**/*'])
        .pipe(gulp.dest('apps/src/assets/fonts'));
});

gulp.task('clean-copy', () => {
    del(['apps/src/assets/fonts']);
});

gulp.task('copy-assets', gulp.series(['clean-copy', 'copy-fonts']), (done) => {
    console.log("Gulp is running...");
    done();
});
```

When i run this command: `gulp copy-assets`, i get the below error:

```
[11:59:06] The following tasks did not complete: copy-assets
[11:59:06] Did you forget to signal async completion?
```

Comment: Try `gulp.task('clean-copy', (cb) => {
    del(['apps/src/assets/fonts'] ); cb();
});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this code:

```
gulp.task('copy-assets', gulp.series(['clean-copy', 'copy-fonts']), (done) => {
    console.log("Gulp is running...");
    done();
});
```

the task has three arguments - that is gulp v3 syntax, not gulp 4.  So change that to

```
gulp.task('copy-assets', gulp.series(['clean-copy', 'copy-fonts'], (done) => {
    console.log("Gulp is running...");
    done();
));
```

The `done` return is now within the `gulp.series` arguments.  Also make this change, I think it will be necessary:

```
gulp.task('clean-copy', (cb) => { 
  del(['apps/src/assets/fonts'] ); 
  cb(); 
});
```